# tableDnD container scrolling

Tags: javascript, tablednd

does anyone know if tableDnD (http://isocra.github.io/TableDnD/) can handle div container scrolling so that when I use a table with a large number of rows, and I drag a row up to above a container then the container scrolls to keep the row in view. (I believe this will work if the container is the the window, but what if it's a div)?

```
// Basic initialization of the 
// DND table
$('#table').tableDnD();
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/decr54bo/26/ for an demo environment (without the ability to scroll).

Answer (score 0):

So I've given up with TableDnD in favour of jQuery's sortable which DOES have the drag scroll functionality. (Sorry TableDnD)